# Dropbox API DbxAuthFinish class

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I was trying to experiment with the Dropbox API tutorial, and the following lines of code don't make sense to me:

```
    // This will fail if the user enters an invalid authorization code.
    DbxAuthFinish authFinish = webAuth.finish(code);
    String accessToken = authFinish.accessToken;

    DbxClient client = new DbxClient(config, accessToken);
```

I don't understand the first line, a new object named `authFinish` of type `DbxAuthFinish` is being declared and then `accessToken` is set equal to `authFinish.accessToken`.

If my understanding of the code is correct why isn't the `new` keyword required?

[Link to the tutorial.](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `webAuth.finish` method returns an already initialized `DbxAuthFinish` instance, so you don't have to include `new` in your code. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/src/com/dropbox/core/DbxWebAuth.java#L244) for the [Dropbox Core Java SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/java), you'll see that the `finish` method in `DbxWebAuth` itself concludes with:

```
return new DbxAuthFinish(finish.accessToken, finish.userId, givenUrlState);
```

Your code then goes on to pull the access token from the `DbxAuthFinish` and use it to initialize a `DbxClient`.